# How to get the key point score from each question in a range and pass it to my sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a short quiz. All of the info from the quiz is passed into a Sheet. This part works fine. My issue is that I can not get the getScores(values) to pull the points from the correct answers and pass them into my sheet. All right answers have 1 point and a wrong answer should place a 0 into the cell. I have spent 2 days trying to sort this out. Any help in doing this correctly is much appreciated.

```js
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var row = sheet.getLastRow();
  var startColumn = 14;
  var endColumn = 18;
  var values = e.values.slice(startColumn - 1, endColumn); // Adjust index for 0-based array
  var scores = getScores(values);

  for (var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
    var score = scores[i];
    var column = startColumn + i - 1;
    sheet.getRange(row, column).setValue(score);
  }
}


function getScores(values) {
  var scores = getScores(values);
  var scoreValue = scores.score;

  if (scoreValue !== 1) {
    scoreValue = 0;
  }

  return scoreValue;
}
```

Currently it places the selected answer (entire text) into the cell instead of the points if correct or a 0 if it was wrong. These are multiple choice questions.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found a solution to your problem. This solutions uses an "on form submit" event type and it is being set "From Form" rather than from Spreadsheet.

```
function myFunction(e) {

  const itemResponses = e.response.getGradableItemResponses();
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('YOUR SHEET ID');
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('YOUR SHEET NAME');
  const targetRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  const values = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < itemResponses.length; i++ ){

    const currentResponse = itemResponses[i];
    //if You do not need title  or answer, you can remove them
    const title = currentResponse.getItem().getTitle();
    const answer = currentResponse.getResponse();
    const score = currentResponse.getScore();

     values.push(title,answer,score);

  }

  sheet.getRange(targetRow,1,1,values.length).setValues([values]);//here you can replace value for starting at your desired column.

}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is working. How do I restrict it to index 12+ for example? The first 12 questions are anon user info question with no score needed. This is followed by the 5 questions with a score. Again thanks!

Comment: This is now working the way I need it, thanks

Comment: Hi @JCBluntch If walsys the first 12 questions are no score needed you can start the for loop var i at 11 like this: 

  for (var i = 11; i < itemResponses.length; i++ ){}

Also, if my answer helped you solve your problem it is common use to mark this answer as correct so other SO users can easily find solutions to similar problems. Best

Comment: Hi Matias, Yes, that's what I did to get what I needed. Thank you again. I've marked your answer as correct as well. Thanks!!